# MySQL listings schema

Tags: mysql, join, schema

Say I have a property `listings` table and a `listings_categories` table which determines if the listing is for *sale*, *rent* and/or *season rent*. Depending which categories a listing has (min of 1 required), a price value or timespan (in case of season rent) may be required.

How should I deal with these price fields? Should they be placed in the `listings`, or move them to the `listings_categories` table? These price fields are somewhat essential to the app and will always be displayed -- would I have any problems appending them to the rest of the main listing table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say if listings_categories only has one column and 3 possible fields, you ought to just store all of that in the listings table. No reason to join when you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

If the sale, rent, and season rent values are always specific to the listing (all listings have specific values), and not to the category (values for all categories are the same, regardless of listing) then your `listings` table is where I would put these fields.